# Passing Model Between Silverlight Views

Tags: silverlight, prism

Since the basic navigation mechanism in Silverlight only allows passing arguments in a querystring, when we want to pass complex data (e.g models) between our views, we use the IEventAggregator's pub\sub mechanism.

But the question is - is there a better way to pass complex information between views?
What are the cons of using the IEventAggregator for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why I switched to a ViewModel first approach. Views really aren't configurable nor should they really be passing ViewModels around. It made a lot more sense to me for a ViewModel to load another ViewModel like:

```
Show.Screen<OrderDetailsViewModel>(vm => vm.OrderId = orderId);
```

This is from the [Build your own mvvm framework](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/03/16/build-your-own-mvvm-framework-is-online.aspx) talk and is also similar to how [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why IEventAggregator is bad, maybe it's not so intuitive? When you look at your app - you want to see what's going on and doing events with some data doesn't seem to be good. Event is event. You can share some data via Region's context in PRISM.

I'm solving same kind of issues using MEF. So, you can define something like

```
[Export]
public class MyModelService
{
    // Code here whatever shared data you want
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    // Import this shared ModelService
    [Import]
    public MyModelService ModelService
}
```

So, if you had some data in ModelService  - by default MEF will compose it just once (effectively making it shared) and every time you import it inside ViewModel this instance will be there. Then you can use Events originated from ModelService to tell components when data updated, etc.

Comment: From your answer, I get an impression that you are suggesting not to pass data with events. Events can have data associated with them and thats why the EventArgs exist. We can define custome class which inherits EventArgs. That is a standard practice. Is there any reason you advocate not using it?

Comment: The Region context is not good enough since the view I'm navigating to is not necessarily on the same Region as the view with the data, *and* it's not strongly typed. 
I've thought of a MEF-based solution kind of like you propose, but it feels kind of awkward to create a service to simply hold data, and besides - to what would it scale - an additional service per model?

Comment: @NileshGule I'm not Guru by any means. I'm just developer as most of us. If I see application where MODEL data passed in through events - I will be confused. Yes, you can pass data, but WHAT data you pass is where difference is. If you pass some "state" data - like shared model - this will get over the head quickly

Comment: @sternr I just mentioned Region context in case you didn't look at it. I'm using MEF with PRISM (not Unity) so, to me having concept of "services" that I can import at any place thru application seems very nice. I need security? No problem. Import SecurityManager... And so on. I'm using IdeaBlade DevForce for data - so I keep their EntityManager inside my own ModelManager that I import/share. Any way you look at it - you need to hold data somehow. Service/Import will work best if you plan to do TDD. Also, I go with interfaces (skipped that in my code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a Session idea, like in ASP.NET. I've defined a static object named SilverlightSession and add a Values property of type Dictionary. Then I just add to the values dictionary or update it and cast it

```
public static class SilverlightSession
{
  public static Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; private set; }
}
```

in the app.xaml.cs startup:

```
SilverlightSession.Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Then you can have your models in "session" until the application closes.

Comment: You might as well use singletons and injection instead rather than introduce a global static loosely typed collection. ASP.Net sessions are a necessity, but not a desirable way of doing it when you have strongly typed alternatives available.